# upscaling videos on iMac 5k with VLC (or other player) - just enlarge the window?

Tags: imac, video, resolution, vlc, macos

I have lots of old videos with low resolution. For example:

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L4a
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Codec ID                                 : 20
Duration                                 : 1 min 46 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 2 743 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 4 000 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 3 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 28.508 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 2.097 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 40.816 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.313
```

I play them with VLC. To upscale the video I just make the window bigger. Is there any better way?
Is there any macOS Sierra software providing better upscaling experience of legacy videos?

Comment: The unfortunate answer is there is nothing you can really do if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I think the simplest solution is to sit further away & not wear your glasses. [I'm only half joking, there's really not a lot you can do to seamlessly upscale so far, nothing worth the effort anyway] VLC is going to do a 'fair' job of it on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that your sources are low quality and going to a larger, higher resolution screen is just going to make them look more crummy than on a lower res, smaller screen unless you actually process the videos.
You can try interpolating the sources but it's a long process and probably not worth it. The best option is XMedia Recode. You can thank me later ;)

Comment: XMedia Recode is only available for Windows?

Comment: Yep, but I don't believe there's a freeware for mac that does the same thing. Any old win PC can run it.